# I can't detect \n character in XMl parsing [android]

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I try to parse an XML file with the DOM method (`EventElement.getAttribute("string")`)
but I couldn't detect the Warp (e.g "\n") but when I open it in the browser and open its source (ctrl+u) I see the warps.

when i use

string.split("\n") 
string.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")) ;
string.split("
");

all of them dosen't work

Thank you for any help

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to detect the \n in the attribute itself, or after the </TAG> ends?

Answer (score 0):

you shoud search not for the "\n" but for `System.getProperty("line.separator");`.

Comment: how do you try to detect the symbol, can you please show the code?

Comment: am splinting my string as string.split("\n")   even string.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))  doesn't work!!

Comment: i don know if it is legal to do it :P     it contains news of matches  * stance : scorers_1="Xavi (10e) Pedro (18e) Villa (55e, 57e) Jeffran (90e)" when i see its source (firefox ctrl+n) i see the warps not in the xml :)

Answer (score 0):

The code that generates your XML should wrap the text content in CDATA[]

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8